# Broadcast Receiver listening for last installed app

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I've created an app that listens for the last installed app on my phone, and notifies me when a new app was installed. Right now it is correctly notifying me for the last installed app, but it also notifies me when any apps are updated. **Does anyone know how to JUST listen for the last installed app, and not listen for when an app goes through an update?**

Here is my code:

```
public class NewInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    Log.d("tag_name", "NewInstallReceiver" + intent.getAction());

    final PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    ApplicationInfo ai;
    try {

        ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(intent.getData().getSchemeSpecificPart(), 0);
        Log.d("tag_name", "Application Info" + ai);

    } catch (final PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        ai = null;
    }

    List<PackageInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    Collections.sort(packages, new Comparator<PackageInfo>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(PackageInfo p1, PackageInfo p2) {
            return Long.toString(p2.firstInstallTime).compareTo(Long.toString(p1.firstInstallTime));
        }
    });
}
}
```

My intent filters for Broadcast Receiver

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.natalie.listener.NewInstallReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="100">
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL"/>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"/>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_DATA_CLEARED"/>
            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED"/>
            <data android:scheme="package"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: What are the actions you are listening to?

Comment: @jaibatrik Currently when I get the package info "ai", it is getting the package info of (1) new installed apps and (2) any apps that just got updated. And I just want to get package info of the last installed app, not the updated ones.

Comment: What is the intent filter for `NewInstallReceiver`?

Comment: @jaibatrik I added my manifest code above for what intent filters I currently have.

Answer (score 0):

With this code you can see a application was installed on your phone before :

```
PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
ApplicationInfo appInfo = pm.getApplicationInfo("application package name", 0);
String appFile = appInfo.sourceDir; 
long installed = new File(appFile).lastModified();
```